# How to get the height of the content div to be 100% of the screen

Tags: css

I want to expand the `.content` which is of blue-ish colour to the bottom of the screen.
I have tried

```
.content {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}
```

Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/39v5ehwx/

Please check it after expanding the window size to full you will see that the bluish content area doesn't stretch to the bottom. Inside the `.content` the height only works in pixels

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in the question itself and don't expect us to debug your full code

Comment: Make sure every parent element also has 100% height, up to and including `body|html` - Either that, or `100vh`. Percentages are a _relative_ unit, meaning they have to be a percentage _of something_. **Note** It looks like you have a toolbar at the top - neither 100% or 100vh are a good fit for you since you'll have some overflow at the bottom (the height of the toolbar). You can combine both units with [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) if you know the height of the toolbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a div 100% height of the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your jsfiddle, you need to make the parent element `100vh`, then you can do some work with `display:flex` on the other elements.

Replace `height:100%` on `.wrapper` with:

```
.wrapper {
    /* height: 100% */
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then, replace `min-height: 100%` with `flex: 1`. This will stretch this element the full height of the remaining space (this works along with `display:flex` on the parent):

```
.content-wrapper {
  /* min-height: 100%; */
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: using height 100vh causes double vertical scroll bars  i.imgur.com/bu5fFiK.jpg

Comment: @vlksie Do you need the `.content` to be scrollable? and the rest to stay in place? I will edit my answer once I know a little more.